# How should I integrate $e^{x^6-11x-66}$?

Tags: integration

I tried: 
$$ \begin{align*} \int e^{x^6-11x-66}dx
                  &=  \frac{e^{x^6-11x-66}\cdot(x^6-11x-66)}{(x^6-11x-66)} \\
                  &=  e^{x^6-11x-66} \\
\end{align*} $$
Can this work?

Comment: You cannot use the power rule if the power is not a constant.

Comment: Is the following the full problem  $\int e^{x^6-11x-66} dx$ ?

Comment: I think you'll have to do it numerically.

Comment: It is the one side of a Bernoulli equation I am trying to work out

Comment: (-e^9-11x-66)) / 11*V = ∫ex6−11x−66dx

Comment: I tried editing the math into proper formatting. Do my edits accurately reflect the intent of the question?

Comment: Worth noting:  it is very easy to verify (by differentiation) that your proposed integral is incorrect.

Comment: @AndrewLi: I fail to see the power rule at work.

Comment: Yes, it is accurate so it can be integrated. I also wanted to leave the problem without integrating.

Comment: I don't know if it could or how to do it.

Comment: This integral doesn't have an anti-derivative in elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

No,

$$\left(e^{x^6-11x-66}\right)'\ne e^{x^6-11x-66}.$$

Besides, it is well known that the only function that is its own antiderivative is $e^x$.

Comment: It may be a multiple of $e^x$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: after all, I will revert to my previous formulation, as it is pretty implicit that you can apply a multiplicative constant, including $0$.